# Cassandra Python-Driver -- ReadFailure Error

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm experiencing a ReadFailure error when making a "SELECT" query through the python-driver for Cassandra.

My instance of Cassandra is a single local node. It was installed via a tar file, versus installing it as a service.

I have a keyspace called "Documents" and a table with two columns, name and object. Name is the text datatype and object is the blob datatype. The blob objects are pickled python class instances. The description of the keyspace/table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "Documents".table (
    name text PRIMARY KEY,
    object blob
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

There are 3509 rows contained within this table and each object is approx. 25kb of data. (so I'm estimating ~90Mb of data in the object column.)  I'm attempting to run a simple line of python cassandra code :

```
rows = session.execute("SELECT name, object FROM table")
```

This query will execute in CQLSH, but I get a cassandra.ReadFailure error when I attempt it in python. This is the specific error:

```
cassandra.ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'consistency': 'LOCAL_ONE', 'required_responses': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'failures': 1}
```

and in the log file of cassandra this is what is produced:

```
WARN  [ReadStage-4] 2018-02-13 14:53:12,319 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:167 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-4,10,main]: {}
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2598) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:162) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:134) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DataOutputBuffer.validateReallocation(DataOutputBuffer.java:134) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DataOutputBuffer.calculateNewSize(DataOutputBuffer.java:152) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DataOutputBuffer.reallocate(DataOutputBuffer.java:159) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DataOutputBuffer.doFlush(DataOutputBuffer.java:119) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.write(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:132) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.write(BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.java:151) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.writeWithVIntLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:296) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.writeValue(AbstractType.java:413) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.Cell$Serializer.serialize(Cell.java:210) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.lambda$serializeRowBody$0(UnfilteredSerializer.java:248) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.applyForwards(BTree.java:1242) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree.apply(BTree.java:1197) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.BTreeRow.apply(BTreeRow.java:172) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody(UnfilteredSerializer.java:236) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:205) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:137) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:125) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:137) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:92) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.serialize(UnfilteredRowIteratorSerializer.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$Serializer.serialize(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:308) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.build(ReadResponse.java:167) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:160) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse$LocalDataResponse.<init>(ReadResponse.java:156) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadResponse.createDataResponse(ReadResponse.java:76) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ReadCommand.createResponse(ReadCommand.java:346) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1886) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2594) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
... 5 common frames omitted
```

In addition to my query working in CQLSH, I can also execute the query from python on other identical tables. The only difference being they have less rows ∴ less data.

I have attempted to change timeout values in the yaml file to not avail, which makes sense because this is not a timeout issue. I have also modified the tombstone_failure_threshold variable in the yaml file, again to no avail.

How can I execute a query on a large dataset without receiving this error. Is it possible to set a batch_size variable? Any guidance at this point would be helpful.

Comment: You probably need to adjust your data model so that it supports a `WHERE` clause.  Tables with large amounts of data don't react well to unbound queries in Cassandra.

Comment: can you open up a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CASSANDRA ? that doesn't look right

Comment: @Aaron we will rethink how we are storing the data. We currently have a table for each 'domain' but maybe instead it would be better to store all data in a single table with an extra column which lets us sort by the 'domain'

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I have reported the bug via your link. [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14235](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14235) I'm new to that whole process so hopefully I provided enough information in an appropriate format. thank you.

Comment: thats perfect thank you